# Как сохранять промежуточные данные в функции Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем мир!
И вопрос сразу таков:
В примере кода функции вы можете увидеть два `SELECT ... AS _query`(строчки 5 и 6) и естественно так делать нельзя; 
Помогите правильно преобразовать агрумент функции `_query` для дальнейшей работы с ним в запросе;
В SQL полный ноль и трогаю его только в крайней необходимости, пробовал объявить переменные через `DECLARE` но постоянно на что-то ругается интерпретатор(если так можно сказать)
СУБД postgresql
Заранее большое спасибо!)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.search_movies(_query character varying)
 RETURNS TABLE(id bigint, _table character varying, nameru character varying, nameen character varying, image text)
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
SELECT regexp_replace(_query, '\M', ':* ', 'gi') AS _query;
SELECT regexp_replace(_query, '\M\:\*(?=(\s+?|)\m)', ':* | ', 'gi') AS _query;
SELECT *
FROM (
       (
         SELECT
           id,
           'movie'               AS _table,
           nameru,
           nameen,
           CAST(posters AS TEXT) AS image
         FROM movies
         WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('ru', _query)
         LIMIT 10
       )
       UNION
       (
         SELECT
           id,
           'staff'                   AS _table,
           staff_name,
           staff_name_en,
           CAST(staff_photo AS TEXT) AS image
         FROM movie_staff
         WHERE tsv @@ to_tsquery('ru', _query)
         LIMIT 10
       )

     ) t
ORDER BY
  CASE
  WHEN _table = 'movie'
    THEN 1
  WHEN _table = 'staff'
    THEN 2
  ELSE 3
  END;
$function$
```

Comment: Я вижу тут только регулярки которые в конце любого слова добавляют `:* `. А вторая, в особо извращенной форме, находит конец слова после которого стоят `:*` и возможно пробелы, после которых начинается следующее слово и меняют этот участок на `:* | `. Что бы это ни значило ... Это надо к реальным данным, поступающим на вход, применить, что бы понять зачем это нужно и что с этим делать

Comment: Да, все верно, это для полнотекстового поиска, в функцию я хочу передавать необработанные строки типа: "Movie na"

Вопрос же заключается в том как мне использовать результат этих двух реплейсов в основном селекте

Comment: Не знаю как в постгресе это сохранять, по моему проще в сам запрос добавить. В начале перед основным select пишите `with Q(query) as(
 SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace('abc efg ', '\M', ':* ', 'gi'),'\M\:\*(?=\s*\m)', ':* | ', 'gi')
)
` и в самом запросе в части FROM добавляете таблицу Q и там где надо подставить вычисленное Q.query.

Comment: А вообще в гугле вбиваете "postrgresql хранимые процедуры" и смотрите примеры. там сразу в глаза бросается что после AS в самом начале процедуры пишите declare, описываете переменные, после этого пишется BEGIN а что бы что то внести в переменную пишите `select abc from xxx INTO переменная` (посмотреть в гугле заняло 2 минуты)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Уже искал, так бы сюда не задавал вопрос.
Что касается ошибки при `declare` она была из-за того что язык был указан не `plpgsql`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(_query, '\M', ':* ', 'gi') INTO some_var;
```